# Perl and regex: how to empty a line of text containing several spaces ? (number of spaces can vary)

Tags: regex, perl

Using Perl, I need to empty a string which **contains several spaces**

I can't come out with the correct regex

**Here is my text:**

```
<sentence="I am walking on the street and it is raining" >
</sentence>
```

I want to empty this string to get:

```
<sentence="" >
</sentence>
```

**Here is my code (it is just replacing a string without space):**

```
sub empty_it {

    print "\nSTART replacing WO info !!!\n";
    my $find    = "\<sentence\=\"\\S*\"";
    my $replace = "\<sentence\=\"\"";
    {  
        local @ARGV = ("$_[0]");
        local $^I = '.baz';
        while ( <> ) {
            if (s/$find/$replace/ig) {
                print;
            }
            else {
                print;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably a way to match all content between the two quotes. This can be done by using a negative character class (i.e /"[^"]*"/)

So this would probably work:

```
my $find = '<sentence="[^"]*"';
```

But in general I wouldn't recommend using regular expressions for mangling xml. It is often to fragile and will often break if your input changes the least. For example if it starts using single quotes because it suddenly have to include double quotes inside the content.

Comment: The data shown in the question are not XML. `=` cannot follow an element name in XML.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry. The content you are trying to mangle are not XML. It is just XML-inspired. Why do people insist on reinventing XML like languages that are just as hard to parse as XML but without the possibility of using the standard tools to parse XML?

Comment: the real xml file is : <sentence singing="I am walking on the street and it is raining"> </sentence>

Comment: it xml. I just forgot to put the attribute (singing). Anyway the question is about regex in Perl

Comment: Friends do not let friends parse XML with regular expressions :-) Well XML or not, my answer should work.

Comment: @laurentngu: Well, the old rule is "Never parse XML with regular expressions."

Comment: I am testing it. Actually I use regex text to deliver fast a small script. Later I can use libxml or twig

Comment: @pmakholm your solution is working. Maybe you could help further. Actually the string can be have 2 forms:  <sentence singing= "I am walking on the street and it is raining">  OR <sentence singing="I am walking on the street and it is raining" > . That means there can be a space between = and "

Comment: In regexp language "An optional space" is written as '\s?'. If you can have more than one space it transaltes to '\s*'. So `my $find = '<sentence=\s*"[^"]*"';`

Comment: @pmakholm ok you were the first one to show the correct solution. Chas-owens solution is working well also

Comment: @pmakholm [^"]+ is any text including space ?

Comment: Yes, [^"] matches any characters except the double quote character. And I also agree with all the issues raised by Chas. Owens.

Answer (score 3):

Your immediate problem is that `"\S*"` will not match `"I am walking on the street and it is raining"` because `\S` won't match the spaces between the words.  A better option would be `[^"]+`, this will match anything that isn't a double quote; however, it still has problems if double quotes are allowed in the string (if they are escaped).  Of course, we would need to know the escaping mechanism to fix that problem.

You have several other issues in the code:

1. excessive escaping in your strings
2. failure to use the `qr//` for creating a regex (to avoid escaping completely)
3. The `/i` and `/g` options look like they have been pasted on without understanding what they do
4. an `if` and `else` that have the same contents
5. inconsistent indenting
6. unnecessary quoting of a scalar value
7. `empty_it` is not a very good function name

I have fixed the parts I can fix here:

```
sub empty_it {
    print "\nSTART replacing WO info !!!\n";
    my $find    = qr/<sentence="[^"]+"/;
    my $replace = q/<sentence=""/;
    local $^I   = '.baz';
    local @ARGV = ($_[0]);
    while( <> ) {
        s/$find/$replace/ig;
        print;
    }
}
```

Comment: @chas-owens thanks. Actually a space can also be present between the '=' and the first " .     sentence="hi hello" or sentence= "hi hello"   .  How would you change your solution ?

Comment: I did     my $find=qr/(sentence= "[^"]+"|sentence="[^"]+")/;   . Let me know if better solution

Comment: finally I used yours and pmakholm   :     my $find=qr/<sentence=\s*"[^"]+"/;

Comment: @laurentngu You probably want `qr/<sentence\s*=\s*"[^"]+"/` as it will allow one or more whitespace characters on either side of the equal sign; however, as I mentioned in my answer, this regex is incomplete.  It **will** fail for all sorts of reasons.  For example: `<sentence="I said \"Don't use a regex for XML.\"">`

Answer (score 2):

It really is better to use a tried and tested XML module for procesing XML data. This program uses [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig) to make the changes that you asked for

As far as I can tell, you want to check all the `singing` attributes of `sentence` elements and set them to empty strings if they contain whitespace

The `$twig` object is created with the `keep_spaces` option enabled. This retains all whitespace PCDATA and so keeps the formatting and indentation of the original file

Once the data is parsed, a call to `get_xpath` finds all the `sentence` elements that have a `singing` attribute containing at least one whitespace character. (Note that this is a non-standard XPath language unique to `XML::Twig`)

The loop just sets the `singing` attribute to the null string for all of these elements, and `$twig->print` outputs the modified data

Note that the other `sentence` element with a `singing` attribute of `NOSPACES` is output unchanged because it doesn't match the `get_xpath` search

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;
my $twig = XML::Twig->new(keep_spaces => 1);

$twig->parse(*DATA);

for my $sentence ( $twig->get_xpath('//sentence[@singing =~ /\s/]') ) {
  $sentence->set_att(singing => '');
}
$twig->print;

__DATA__
<root>
  <sentence singing="I am walking on the street and it is raining" >
  </sentence>
  <sentence singing="NOSPACES" >
  </sentence>
</root>
```

**output**

```xml
<root>
  <sentence singing="">
  </sentence>
  <sentence singing="NOSPACES">
  </sentence>
</root>
```

Comment: thanks, I will use Twig and your example in my next script version

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the opposite of a char.

```
my $find = '<sentence="[^"]*"';
my $replace = '<sentence=""';
s/$find/$replace/g;
```